# Trigger AWS Rekognition Custom Labels via Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rekognition

My s3 bucket and AWS Rekognition model are both in us-east-1. My lambda which is also in us-east-1 is triggered by an upload into my s3 bucket. I pasted the auto generated code from the model (for python) and used it in my lambda function.  I have even tried giving full access to my s3 bucket (allowing public access with full permission) but when I trigger the lambda I get this exception

```
[ERROR] InvalidS3ObjectException: An error occurred (InvalidS3ObjectException) when calling the DetectCustomLabels operation: Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 80, in lambda_handler
    label_count=show_custom_labels(model,bucket,photo, min_confidence)
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 59, in show_custom_labels
    response = client.detect_custom_labels(Image={'S3Object': {'Bucket': bucket, 'Name': photo}},
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 676, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

I am printing out my bucket name and key in the logs and they are fine. My key has a folder path included (folder1/folder2/image.jpg).

How can I get over this error?

Comment: Assuming that you've verified the S3 permissions of the Lambda and you've verified that the bucket/key you're referencing are actually correct and the object actually exist, then it's not going to be easy to debug this without code.

Comment: giving my lambda role the required s3 access made it work. thanks for the pointer!